# Bootstrap Navbar Collapse Not Showing List

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using bootstrap navbar and I have a collapsible navbar. But I am facing a strange problem, whenever I open my site  i.e mobile phone or tablet (actually for which devices I need the collapsible navbar), the button appears but I'm not able to open the navbar. This should not happen. If I click on the navbar button (three line button) nothing happens.

```
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button> 
          </div>

          <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li>
                <a href="menu-categories.html">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span>
                  <br class="hidden-xs">Menu
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
                  <br class="hidden-xs">About
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate"></span>
                  <br class="hidden-xs">Awards
                </a>
              </li>
              <li id="phone" class="hidden-xs">
                <a href="tel:410-602-5008">
                  <span>410-602-5008</span>
                </a>
                <div>* We Deliver</div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your jQuery version. I hope this will fix your problem. Here is demo link: https://codepen.io/shamimipt/pen/abLKRrx

````
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>```
````